# How do I turn off the login notification sound on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded to Yosemite. I hear a strange 'swoosh' sound whenever I login to my early-2013 13" Retina MacBook Pro. How do I turn it off?

Comment: The 'swoosh' sound is very likely to be from an application, not from the OS itself.

See if you have things like Skype or iMessage open, where the application tries to maintain a network connection and restores it when waking up.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me on mavericks:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4001727?start=15

Also this free program seems to solve the issue

http://auto-mute.com/

Comment: What you suggested is for turning off the startup sound (at boot). What I am talking about is the sound which comes every time I wake up the computer from sleep.

Comment: You get a sound on wake?